# How to get my C++ program to detect the Ñ

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I am working on a OCR project and I am in the training phase, so the goal is for my program to detect the characters as objects in an image and allow them to be classified.
The problem is that I cannot get it with the Ñ because it is formed by two objects (the N and the stick).

Do you know if there is any way to get it classified as a single object?

Here is the program:

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

// global variables 
const int MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 30;

const int RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 20;
const int RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 30;


 //////////////////////////////////////
int main() {

    cv::Mat imgTrainingNumbers;         // input image
    cv::Mat imgGrayscale;               // 
    cv::Mat imgBlurred;                 // declare various images
    cv::Mat imgThresh;                  //
    cv::Mat imgThreshCopy;              //

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > ptContours;        // declare contours vector
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> v4iHierarchy;                    // declare contours hierarchy

cv::Mat matClassificationInts;      // these are our training classifications, note we will have to perform some conversions before writing to file later

// these are our training images, due to the data types that the KNN object KNearest requires, we have to declare a single Mat,
// then append to it as though it's a vector, also we will have to perform some conversions before writing to file later
cv::Mat matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats;

// possible chars we are interested in are digits 0 through 9 and capital letters A through Z, put these in vector intValidChars
std::vector<int> intValidChars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                                   'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
                                   'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 
                                   'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

imgTrainingNumbers = cv::imread("caracteres_prueba.png");          // read in training numbers image

if (imgTrainingNumbers.empty()) {                               // if unable to open image
    std::cout << "error: image not read from file\n\n";         // show error message on command line
    return(0);                                                  // and exit program
}

cv::cvtColor(imgTrainingNumbers, imgGrayscale, CV_BGR2GRAY);        // convert to grayscale

cv::GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale,              // input image
    imgBlurred,                             // output image
    cv::Size(5, 5),                         // smoothing window width and height in pixels
    0);                                     // sigma value, determines how much the image will be blurred, zero makes function choose the sigma value

// filter image from grayscale to black and white
cv::adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred,           // input image
    imgThresh,                              // output image
    255,                                    // make pixels that pass the threshold full white
    cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,         // use gaussian rather than mean, seems to give better results
    cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV,                  // invert so foreground will be white, background will be black
    11,                                     // size of a pixel neighborhood used to calculate threshold value
    2);                                     // constant subtracted from the mean or weighted mean

cv::imshow("imgThresh", imgThresh);         // show threshold image for reference

imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.clone();          // make a copy of the thresh image, this in necessary b/c findContours modifies the image

cv::findContours(imgThreshCopy,             // input image, make sure to use a copy since the function will modify this image in the course of finding contours
    ptContours,                             // output contours
    v4iHierarchy,                           // output hierarchy
    cv::RETR_EXTERNAL,                      // retrieve the outermost contours only
    cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);               // compress horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leave only their end points

for (int i = 0; i < ptContours.size(); i++) {                           // for each contour
    if (cv::contourArea(ptContours[i]) > MIN_CONTOUR_AREA) {                // if contour is big enough to consider
        cv::Rect boundingRect = cv::boundingRect(ptContours[i]);                // get the bounding rect

        cv::rectangle(imgTrainingNumbers, boundingRect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);      // draw red rectangle around each contour as we ask user for input

        cv::Mat matROI = imgThresh(boundingRect);           // get ROI image of bounding rect

        cv::Mat matROIResized;
        cv::resize(matROI, matROIResized, cv::Size(RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT));     // resize image, this will be more consistent for recognition and storage

        cv::imshow("matROI", matROI);                               // show ROI image for reference
        cv::imshow("matROIResized", matROIResized);                 // show resized ROI image for reference
        cv::imshow("imgTrainingNumbers", imgTrainingNumbers);       // show training numbers image, this will now have red rectangles drawn on it

        int intChar = cv::waitKey(0);           // get key press

        if (intChar == 27) {        // if esc key was pressed
            return(0);              // exit program
        }
        else if (std::find(intValidChars.begin(), intValidChars.end(), intChar) != intValidChars.end()) {     // else if the char is in the list of chars we are looking for . . .

            matClassificationInts.push_back(intChar);       // append classification char to integer list of chars

            cv::Mat matImageFloat;                          // now add the training image (some conversion is necessary first) . . .
            matROIResized.convertTo(matImageFloat, CV_32FC1);       // convert Mat to float

            cv::Mat matImageFlattenedFloat = matImageFloat.reshape(1, 1);       // flatten

            matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats.push_back(matImageFlattenedFloat);       // add to Mat as though it was a vector, this is necessary due to the
            // data types that KNearest.train accepts
        }   // end if
    }   // end if
}   // end for

std::cout << "training complete\n\n";

// save classifications to file ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cv::FileStorage fsClassifications("classifications.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);           // open the classifications file

if (fsClassifications.isOpened() == false) {                                                        // if the file was not opened successfully
    std::cout << "error, unable to open training classifications file, exiting program\n\n";        // show error message
    return(0);                                                                                      // and exit program
}

fsClassifications << "classifications" << matClassificationInts;        // write classifications into classifications section of classifications file
fsClassifications.release();                                            // close the classifications file

// save training images to file ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cv::FileStorage fsTrainingImages("images.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);         // open the training images file

if (fsTrainingImages.isOpened() == false) {                                                 // if the file was not opened successfully
    std::cout << "error, unable to open training images file, exiting program\n\n";         // show error message
    return(0);                                                                              // and exit program
}

fsTrainingImages << "images" << matTrainingImagesAsFlattenedFloats;         // write training images into images section of images file
fsTrainingImages.release();                                                 // close the training images file

return(0);
```

}

Comment: you can cluster nearby (just in vertical direction) contours. That's also the same problem you'll have with an _"i"_. (Writing the code in english might also help)

Comment: I forgot to edit the code sorry, but I've already edited it, thanks!

Comment: What is the problem in training them as two separate character, but at the time of detection you may write special cases to treat detection of both character as single one.

Answer (score -1):

first you have an error in

```
 int intChar = cv::waitKey(0);
```

it must be

```
char intChar = cv::waitKey(0);
```

try it and if ther are error tell me

Comment: `int intChar = cv::waitKey(0);` is perfectly fine according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7).

Comment: But when you get character from screen you must declare that as char to can get number and character ....... I used that code before so I tell you what happened with me

Comment: `cv::waitKey` will return values **greater than 127** if you press any [High ASCII](http://fsymbols.com/images/ascii.png) keys, thus overflowing your `char` variable (which ranges from -128 to 127). So, storing the key code in a `char` variable is not recommended. Anyways, your answer is not relevant to the OP's problem so you should consider removing it.

Comment: I know that but CV:: waitkey will take the value from keyboard that you enter so if it's int then take number only but if it char it will take character and number